# On the homotopy group of a mapping cylinder

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Suppose that a space $A$ homotopy dominated by a space $X$. i.e.,  there exist continuous maps $f:A\longrightarrow X$ and $g:X\longrightarrow A$ so that $g\circ f\simeq 1_A$. Also, let $\phi :K\longrightarrow A$ be a  continuous map. Put $\phi'=f\circ \phi:K\longrightarrow X$. We know that $M_{\phi}\simeq A$ and $M_{\phi'}\simeq X$, where $M_{\phi}=\frac{K\times I \cup A}{(k,1)\sim \phi (k)}$ is the mapping cylinder of $\phi$. Also, it is a well-known fact that  $\pi_1 (K)$ acts on the whole long exact sequence of homotopy groups for $(M_{\phi},K\times \{ 1\})$ and $(M_{\phi'},K\times \{ 1\})$, the action commuting with the various maps in the sequence.

My question is :

Is $\pi_2 (M_{\phi},K\times \{ 1\})$ a direct summand of $\pi_2 (M_{\phi'},K\times \{ 1\})$ as $\mathbb{Z}\pi_1 (K)$-module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $h: M_\phi \to M_{\phi’}$ which agrees with $f$ on $A$ and is the identity on $K \times I$; $h$ is well-defined by definition of $\phi’$. Then the homotopy equivalences of the mapping cylinders to their bases shows that $h$ has a left homotopy inverse, since $f$ does. Hence, $h$ induces an inclusion of a direct summand $h_\ast: \pi_2(M_\phi, K) \to \pi_2(M_{\phi’}, K)$.

This $h_\ast$ should be equivariant with respect to the action of $\pi_1(K)$, although I’m not sure how to show this at the moment.

Comment: I think you define  $h:M_{‎\phi‎} \longrightarrow M_{‎\phi '‎}$ by $[a]\mapsto [f(a)]$ and $[k,t]\mapsto [k,t]$‎. ‎Obviously‎, ‎$h$ is a continuous map‎. ‎Also‎, ‎$r_2 \circ h=f\circ r_1$ and  $h(X)=X$, where $r_1‎ :‎M_{‎\phi‎} \longrightarrow A$ and $r_2‎ :‎M_{‎\phi‎ '}\longrightarrow X$ are deformation retractions‎. ‎So‎, ‎we can consider the map $h$ as a map $(A,K)\longrightarrow (X,K)$‎. Is this correct?

Comment: The pair $(A,K)$ does not make sense since we only have a map $\phi$ of $A$ into $K$. But the equation $r_2h = fr_1$ is exactly what is needed to show that $h$ has a left homotopy inverse.

Comment: How do I find a relative map like $d:(X,K)\longrightarrow (A,K)$ so that $d\circ h\simeq 1_{(A,K)}$?

Comment: I mean the pair $(M_{\phi},K\times \{1\})$. But how?

Comment: I tried to do that but there was a problem.

Comment: Let $s_2$ be a homotopy inverse to $r_2$; then $s_1gr_2h = s_1gfr_1 \sim s_1r_1 \sim id$. So $s_1gr_2$ is what we’re looking for. It should be possible to choose all homotopies to be relative, through the form of the mapping cylinder.

Comment: That is right. But could you tell me how to choose all homotopies to be relative?

Comment: Indeed my problem is that I don't know how to do this.

Comment: The only thing I don't understand about the problem is that $s_1 gr_2$ can be relative.